# Unable scan character in while loop

Tags: c

i want infinite scan
this is my code:

```
int main() {
    int i=1;
    char score;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Please Input No %d of char",i);
        scanf("%C",&score);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

my output:

```
Please Input No 1 of char:A
Please Input No 2 of char:B
Please Input No 3 of char:Please Input No 4 of char:C
Please Input No 5 of char:Please Input No 6 of char:
```

how do i fix my i variable in while loop normal.
thanks

Comment: Pro tip: If you want to read in a line and then parse that line, write code that reads in a line and then parses that line. Don't ask the user to enter in a line and then read just a character -- that way lies pain.

Comment: Note that `%C` is a Microsoft-specific [`scanf()` conversion specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/scanf-type-field-characters?view=vs-2019) — and given that you're using `scanf()`, it means that you're passing it a wide character (and 'opposite size character' — see the link).  Except you're not passing a wide character.  Some versions of Linux don't recognize `%C` at all.  On macOS, `%C` is the same as `%lc` — which means a wide character is expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `getchar();` after `scanf()`

```
int main() {
    int i=1;
    char score;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Please Input No %d of char\n", i);
        scanf("%c",&score);
        getchar();

        //or

        scanf(" %c", &score);
        // don't need getchar() here.
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `%C` isn't standard.

And `scanf("%c",&score);` is taking a `char` but while We are pressing `Enter` this is an another input. So, we need `getchar()`

Comment: It would be good to explain why this is needed and also point out the change from `%C` to `%c`.

Comment: You may want `getchar()` in a loop in case `"123 bananas"` is entered.

Comment: Users are perverse creatures and do anything and everything wrong given the slightest opportunity.  You expect them to type a nice short 'word' and they type 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious'.  You expect them to type a single character and a newline, and they type many characters before the newline.  If it weren't for users, programming would be a lot easier.  It would also be a lot less lucrative as an occupation, so you can't do without them.  But you do have to deal with their peculiarities and quirks, and not following either instructions or expectations is a quirk you must handle.

Comment: Also, a better technique than using `getchar()` is to use `" %c"` (with a blank before the `%c` conversion specification).  The blank causes `scanf()` to skip zero or more white space characters — trailing blanks and tabs, and newlines, and leading white space, only stopping when it comes across something that isn't white space.  That works well; if the user types `123` and newline, you get to see all three digits.  If the user types `b`, return, return, return, `c`, then the code sees `b` and `c` only.  Do ***NOT*** use trailing white space in the format string; that is a UX disaster.

Comment: @Jonathan, You write the exact answer. What I knew, I gave it to answer. During char input, I always use getchar(). You can write an answer. It will be better and people will get valuable answer.